# Django CBV RedirectView with cookie

Tags: django, cookies

How can I set cookie in Django RedirectView before redirect?

I interesting not how to set cookie itself, but where can I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override any method you need and put the cookie related thing there, 
for example `get` or `dispatch`, given that RedirectView inherits from django.views.generic.View.

for example, overriding dispatch

```
class Yourclass(RedirectView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #youknow how to set cookie here
        return super(Yourclass, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem.

```
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(PartnerRedirectView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  #one year
    expires = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age), "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
    response.set_cookie(key, value, max_age=max_age, expires=expires)
    return response
```